# Help with solving for $a$ in $\ln(x-a) = \frac12 \ln(x-b) + \frac12 \ln(x+b)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I’m trying to solve for $a$ given some $b$ for the equation:

$$\ln(x-a) = \frac12 \ln(x-b) + \frac12 \ln(x+b)$$

Raise both sides to $e$

$$x-a= e^{\frac{1}{2}(\ln(x-b)+\ln(x+b))}$$

Which be written as

$$x-a= e^{\ln((x-b)^{1/2})+\ln((x+b)^{1/2})}$$

Which can be simplified to

$$x-a= (x-b)^{\frac12} + (x+b)^{\frac12} $$

But then I’m not sure what to do... A hint would be appreciated or if I’m on the wrong track, some gentle correction would be welcome.

Comment: Are you solving for $x$ or $a$? Use properties of logarithms: $\log_ab^c=c\log_ab$ and $\log_a(pq)=\log_a(p)+\log_a(q)$.

Comment: Um.... $e^{\ln A + \ln B} \ne A + B$. Instead $e^{\ln A + \ln B} = e^{\n A }e^{\ln B} = AB$.  Noe you can use the rule $\ln A + \ln B = \ln (A\cdot B)$ if you want.  But you *can't* do anything resembling $\ln A + \ln B underbrace{=}_{!!!NOT!!!!} \ln (A+ B)$ which is what raising $e$ to $e^{\ln A + \ln B}underbrace{=}_{!!!NOT!!!!} A+B$ is doing.

Comment: Um.... $e^{\ln A + \ln B} \ne A + B$. Instead $e^{\ln A + \ln B} = e^{\ln A }e^{\ln B} = AB$.  Note you can use the rule $\ln A + \ln B = \ln (A\cdot B)$ if you want.  But you *can't* do anything resembling $\ln A + \ln B \underbrace{=}_{!!!NOT!!!!} \ln (A+ B)$ which is what raising $e$ to $e^{\ln A + \ln B}\underbrace{=}_{!!!NOT!!!!} A+B$ is doing.

Comment: Why do you assume that $a$ can be solved in terms of $b$ indendently of $x$?  It cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $$x-a= e^{\ln((x-b)^{1/2})+\ln((x+b)^{1/2})}$$
> Which can be simplified to
> $$x-a= (x-b)^{\frac12} + (x+b)^{\frac12}$$

No!  It can't!.

$$e^{\ln((x-b)^{1/2})+\ln((x+b)^{1/2})} = $$

$$e^{\ln((x-b)^{1/2})}\cdot e^{ln((x+b)^{1/2})}=$$

$(x-b)^{\frac 12}(x+b)^{\frac 12}=$.

So you end up with

$$x-a=(x-b)^{\frac 12}(x+b)^{\frac 12}=[(x-b)(x+b)]^{\frac 12} = (x^2 - b^2)^{\frac 12}$$.

Or if you use just log identities

$$\ln(x-a) = \frac12 \ln(x-b) + \frac12 \ln(x+b)$$

$$=\ln [(x-b)^\frac 12] + \ln [(x+b)^\frac 12]$$

$$= \ln([(x-b)^\frac 12][(x+b)^\frac 12])$$

And so $x-a = [(x-b)^\frac 12][(x+b)^\frac 12]$

.....

In any event $a = x- \sqrt{x^2 -b^2}$.

You *can't* solve for $a$ in terms of $b$ without regard to $x$.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying my mistake and showing both ways to solve!

Answer (score 4):

Multiply by 2

$$
2\ln{(x-a)}=\ln{(x+b)}+\ln{(x-b)}\\
\ln{(x-a)^{2}}=\ln{(x^{2}-b^{2})}\\
(x-a)^{2}=x^{2}-b^{2}
$$

Comment: Which will then become $- 2xa + a^2 = b^2$ but from what I understand in my text, it seems that x should not be in the answer... maybe there’s calculus involved that I didn’t anticipate

Comment: the answer is $a=x-\sqrt{x^{2}-b^{2}}$, note that $x-a$ should be positive

Comment: "but from what I understand in my text, it seems that x should not be in the answer"  It may seem that way but the text is misleading.  You can not eliminate $x$ from the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Combine the logarithms on the right-hand side by $\ln(x\cdot y)=\ln(x)+\ln(y)$ and $\ln(x^y)=y\ln(x)$:

\begin{align}\frac12 \ln(x-b) + \frac12 \ln(x+b)&=\frac12\Big(\ln(x-b)+\ln(x+b)\Big)
\\&=\frac 12\Big(\ln\big[(x-b)(x+b)\big]\Big)
\\&=\ln\left(\sqrt{x-b}~\sqrt{x+b}\right).
\end{align}

Therefore, we find

\begin{align}\ln(x-a)&=\ln\left(\sqrt{x-b}~\sqrt{x+b}\right)\\
x-a&=\sqrt{x-b}~\sqrt{x+b}\\
a&=x-\sqrt{x-b}~\sqrt{x+b},
\end{align}

under the assumption that $(x-a),(x-b),(x+b)$ are all positive real numbers greater than zero.

Answer (score 1):

We can easily prove this property of logarithms that
$$
\ln (AB) = \ln(A) + \ln(B)
$$

On the RHS of your question we have
$$
1/2 \left( \ln(x-b) + \ln(x+b)\right) 
$$

From the property stated above

$$1/2 \left( \ln (x^2 -b^2) \right)\tag{1} $$

This property of logarithms can also be proved easily
$$
\ln (A^C)= C ~\ln(A)$$
Using this property for (1) to get
$$ \text{RHS} ~= \ln (x^2 -b^2)^{1/2}\\
\text{LHS} ~=~ \text{RHS} \\
\ln (x-a) = \ln (x^2 -b^2)^{1/2} \\
x-a = (x^2 -b^2)^{1/2}$$
Now, you can easily solve that algebraic equation.

Hope it helps!